# How do i increase the value of my text field when i press the plus button and decrease when i press the minus button+ increase/decrease the price

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
function cartElement($productimg, $productname,  $productdesc,$productprice, $productid){
    $element = "
    
    <form action=\"cart.php?action=remove&id=$productid\" method=\"post\" class=\"cart-items\">
        <div class=\"border rounded\">
            <div class=\"row\">
                <div class=\"col-md-3 pl-0\">
                    <img src=$productimg alt=\"Image1\" class=\"img-fluid\">
                </div>
                <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                    <h5 class=\"pt-2\">$productname</h5>
                    <small class=\"text-secondary\">Seller: Phybrid</small>
                    <h5 id=\"price\" name= \"$productname\" value= \"$productprice\" class=\"pt-2\">$$productprice</h5>
                    <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-warning\">Save for Later</button>
                    <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger mx-2\" name=\"remove\">Remove</button>
                </div>
                <div class=\"col-md-3 py-5\">
                    <div class=\"qty\">
                        <button id=\"up\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"incrementValue()\" class=\"qty_up btn border rounded-circle\" value=\"+\" ><i class=\"fas fa-minus\"></i></button>
                        <input id=\"quantity\" name=\"$productname\" type=\"text\"  value=\"1\" placeholder=\"1\" class=\"qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline\" style= \"width: 35%!important;\">
                        <button id=\"down\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"decrementValue()\" class=\"qty_down btn border rounded-circle\" value=\"-\" ><i class=\"fas fa-plus\"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>"; 
    echo  $element;
}
```

^ is the code for the cart element

```
<h6 class="total">$<?php echo $total; ?></h6>
<?php
    $total = 0;
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
        $product_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'product_id');
        $result = $db->getData();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            foreach ($product_id as $id){
                if ($row['id'] == $id){
                    cartElement($row['product_image'], $row['product_name'],$row['product_desc'],$row['product_price'], $row['id']);
                    $total = $total + (int)$row['product_price'];
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "<h5>Cart is Empty</h5>";
    }
?>
```

^ is the code of my total price

I have no idea how to start on this like ive tried so many youtube videos and tried so many codes but nothing worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "increasing the value"?

Comment: Archit Gargi increasing this 
<input id=\"quantity\" name=\"$productname\" type=\"text\"  value=\"1\" placeholder=\"1\" class=\"qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline\" style= \"width: 35%!important;\">

Comment: Oh ok understood

Answer (score 1):

Changed your `HTMLInputElement` type to `'number'` and added a `min` of `1` (supposing that you dont want it to be less than 1).With javascript:

```js
const buttonUp = document.querySelector('#up')
const buttonDown = document.querySelector('#down')

const targetInput = document.querySelector('#quantity')

buttonUp.onclick = () => {
  const total = parseInt(targetInput.value) + 1
  targetInput.value = total
}
buttonDown.onclick = () => {
  if (parseInt(targetInput.value) > 1) {
    const total = parseInt(targetInput.value) - 1
    targetInput.value = total
  }
    
}
```

```html
<div class="qty">
<button id="up" type="button" class="qty_up btn border rounded-circle" value="+" ><i class="fas fa-minus">+</i></button>
<input id="quantity" name="$productname" type="number"  value="1" placeholder="1" class="qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline" style= "width: 35%!important;">
<button id="down" type="button" class="qty_down btn border rounded-circle" value="-" ><i class="fas fa-plus">-</i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: That works but only like for 1 of the components if i would like have 3 components only the top one works the rest doesnt work

Comment: You would need to change it all to use class selectors, instead of ids, since ids must be unique in the entire DOM.

Comment: IncredibleHat, i tried that but that apparently also doesnt work

Comment: Define "doesnt work". Because it absolutely would work to handle multiple sets of quantity boxes on a page, granted you are referring to the correct set based on the button click (use parents/siblings/children for example).

Comment: IncredibleHat 
const buttonUp = document.querySelector(\".qty_up\")
const buttonDown = document.querySelector(\".qty_down\")

const targetInput = document.querySelector(\".qty_input\")
is what i changed but im still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

As IncredibleHat said, you then have to use classes instead of ids, since they have to be unique in your html. Then you could try:

```js
const buttonsUp = document.querySelectorAll('.qty_up')
const buttonsDown = document.querySelectorAll('.qty_down')
    

/* For each of the buttons,
accessing to its nextElementsibling or prevousElementSibling
that's the input field */

    buttonsUp.forEach(btnUp => {
      btnUp.onclick = () => {
        const targetInput = btnUp.nextElementSibling
        const total = parseInt(targetInput.value) + 1
        targetInput.value = total
      }
    })
    buttonsDown.forEach(btnDown => {
      btnDown.onclick = () => {
        const targetInput = btnDown.previousElementSibling
        if (parseInt(targetInput.value) > 1) {
          const total = parseInt(targetInput.value) - 1
          targetInput.value = total
        }
      }
    })
```

```html
<div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty_up btn border rounded-circle" value="+" ><i class="fas fa-minus">+</i></button>
    <input id="quantity" name="$productname" type="number"  value="1" placeholder="1" class="qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline" style= "width: 35%!important;">
    <button type="button" class="qty_down btn border rounded-circle" value="-" ><i class="fas fa-plus">-</i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty_up btn border rounded-circle" value="+" ><i class="fas fa-minus">+</i></button>
    <input id="quantity2" name="$productname" type="number"  value="1" placeholder="1" class="qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline" style= "width: 35%!important;">
    <button type="button" class="qty_down btn border rounded-circle" value="-" ><i class="fas fa-plus">-</i></button>
  </div>
  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty_up btn border rounded-circle" value="+" ><i class="fas fa-minus">+</i></button>
    <input id="quantity3" name="$productname" type="number"  value="1" placeholder="1" class="qty_input form-control w-25 d-inline" style= "width: 35%!important;">
    <button type="button" class="qty_down btn border rounded-circle" value="-" ><i class="fas fa-plus">-</i></button>
  </div>
```

Comment: That doesnt exactly work since its gonna be the cartElement x the amount of products there are in the database, like its the WHOLE element not just that part

Comment: I  mean each cart element has that "qty" div. You were asking for a way to increase input field value via two buttons. What's the point then.

Comment: It still doesnt work even though each cart element has that qty div

Comment: Have you inserted the javascript? Are you getting any errors? Be more precise please

Comment: Alright sorry, There arent any errors and i inserted the javascript but like none of the buttons are doing what they are supposed to do.

Comment: I've used your function cartElement in my localhost. Added the scripts and they work as expected. Note that the buttons that sum have to be in the same container than the input, before it, and also with the substract buttons, but following the input. There must be something that you're missing.

Comment: ask4you i fixed the problem by switching around the plus and the minus and adding the js in the place where the element was supposed to be

Comment: How do i make it so the price goes up everytime i press the plus button and it goes down every time i press the minus button